Is it possible to make Visual Studio C++ build which supports x86 and x64?
How is it possible to make Visual Studio 2022 C++ build an exe-file which runs on x86 and x64 platforms?
I see separate options x86 or x64, but not see something like "AnyCPU".
I tried to google. As Far as I know x86 should be able to run on x64. But I'm not sure is it a good solution if I will end up with x86.

"x86" is the platform that can be run by both x86 and x64.  Is it possible to run x86 assembly on a x64 operating system?

The answer was given as comments in the staging ground: (1) AnyCPU is available only for .NET/CLR code which run on a virtual machine  (2) Native code has to be compiled for a specific architecture, but x64 systems support running 32 bit native code.

x86 will automagically run on x64

obviously not, there's no fat 32/64-bit binary on Windows. The only way is to select the 32 or 64-bit version on installation time or runtime. If you're using .NET then it's compiled into byte code like Java, which is then compiled into the native code. Nowadays there's practically zero x86 code so just compile x86-64

You can make a small launcher program (in x86) which can check if x64 is available, then use that to bootstrap launch your x86 EXE (on a x86 platform), or your x64 EXE (on a x64 platform).

Another question: Do really have a 32-bit Windows to run the program on? Deliveries of new systems were stopped already in 2020.

Native code development like C++ must choose the architecture at build time and it is x86, x64, or ARM64 for Windows.
Generally all Windows x64 client systems can run x86 applications. Windows on ARM64 clients can emulate both x86 and x64. Some Windows Server system do NOT support x86 applications.
With all that said, no modern version of Windows is x86 only. Unless you are trying to run on Windows XP, x64 is perfectly fine and what most applications & games now use.
